# The page is not rendering in UI using spring angularjs and How to make request and response in html format?

Tags: angularjs, maven, spring-mvc

Am doing a simple save operation using spring+hibernate and invoking service call through Angularjs controller,

**angular controller :**

```
var Registration = angular.module('registartion',[]);

    Registration.controller('Reg', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.addUser = function(){    
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "/SpringHibernate/addUser", 
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data : $scope.user
            }).success(function(data) {
        document.getElementById("id_add").innerHTML = data;
    });
        };

    });
```

**spring service :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addUser", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public String adduser(@RequestBody Registration user) { 
        userService.save(user);
        return "success" ;

    }
```

In the above code while click a button in UI which binds the function inside angularjs controller , the spring service url(/addUser) will be invoked.After doing save operation spring returns "success" string which is a JSP page.

The Problem is the success.jsp is not loading in browser after service call but its visible in response body in browser.

Please anyone help me with this issue.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing ViewResolver configuration in your spring xml configuration.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

where prefix is the relative path(root) to your JSP files.

Updated-->

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addUser", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
   @ResponseBody
    public String adduser(@RequestBody Registration user) { 
        userService.save(user);
        return "success" ;

    }
```

Comment: i have this in my xml file. I have doubt that the response from service is in JSON format then how i render it in my UI as html page?can you make me understand this doubt ?

Comment: just add the @ResponseBody to your service like above

Comment: I have added that in service.But i could render the success page content in new html page through angular but not directly render the full page

Comment: <div>{{view}}</div> through this i added success data in new page.but couldnt display the success page directly

Comment: i am unable to understand,you want to display success.jsp or a string in your html file?

Comment: i want to display success.jsp file but in my sample page is displaying..instead i could get the page content in angular http call and display the content through $scope.view in some other page using .success(function(data) {
   document.getElementById("id_add").innerHTML = data;
  });

Comment: can you post your spring configuration file here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66401/discussion-between-re350-and-asthcg).